# UIViewController either leaks memory or crashes app if autoreleased

Tags: iphone

I have this code in my app and it says memory leak at 'gvc'.

```
GameViewController* gvc = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gvc animated:YES];
```

If i modify this code to autorelease view controller, it crashes my app after a while giving error 'Missed Method'

```
GameViewController* gvc = [[[GameViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gvc animated:YES];
```

Is there something wrong with autorelease? How to resolve this memory leak?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which specific tool is telling you there's a memory leak?

Comment: Build and Analyze in XCode shows the memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

You can safely do this:

```
GameViewController* gvc = [[[GameViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gvc animated:YES];
```

or this:

```
GameViewController* gvc = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gvc animated:YES];
[gvc release];
```

They are functionally equivalent and don't cause memory leaks or crashes. Look at your code after `[self.navigationController pushViewController:gvc animated:YES];` to see if you over-release `gvc`.

Comment: I already tried autorelease it says 'Missed Method' and crashes. I just tried [gvc release] after pushViewController line and same result. Also, I do not over release gvc. One thing I would like to add is my app have only one xib (MainWindow.xib) everything else is generated using code. Is it because of that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just release it when you're all done.  If you need it all the time, then put `GameViewController *gvc;` in the header and put `[gvc release];` in the dealloc method.

Comment: This gvc is used in welcome screen, other screen gets pushed and poped on top of welcome screen. Do you think I should use your approach? I thought my Welcome Screen will remain as it is once created and other screens will be allocated -> pushed -> poped -> deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is simply to release the view controller once you've pushed it onto the nav controller.

i.e.:

```
GameViewController* gvc = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gvc animated:YES];
[gvc release];
```

That said, I'd be surprised if the autorelease was actually causing a memory leak at all.

Answer (score 0):

It may be everything. I mean, your first code is obviously leaking, and the second code snippet is ok at first glance, but we don't know what you implement inside that class. Imagine in GameViewController, you have a string property userName, and in its dealloc, you do something like:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [userName release];
    [userName release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Then of course it crashes when you release the controller. You should use gdb backtrace (type "bt" when it crashes) to see exactly where it crashes, or better yet, try to enable NSZombie and use instruments to find out.

Btw as a rule of thumbs in iPhone/iPad programming (where resources are scarce), try to avoid autorelease whenever you can.